# Group by name in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using  `User.where("name LIKE ?", "frodo")` to find users with similar names.
It may return the following users

- frodobaggins
- frodo
- frodo1
- frodo2
- ....

How would I group all users by similar names (partially the same)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "frodo%"])

   or
User.where(["name LIKE ?", "frodo%"])
```

it return array of all user which name start with frodo.

Answer (score 1):

From Divyang's answer, one small change to group users by name:--

```
User.where(["name LIKE ?", "frodo%"]).group(:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord provides a way to support group by clause. Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group